# DeepZoom white images - Imagemagick Vips Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, imagemagick, tile, deepzoom, openseadragon

i have a little cocoa osXa app that uses Vips DZSAVE and imagemagick to create the DeepZoom Tile from a big psb file.

the problem is that it works fine just till a undefined size. i'm managing correctly files about 60.000px X 50.000px 27Gb size but whit bigger files the app is generating a tile made by white images.
No data are written...

i have to manage images around 170.000px X 170.000px between 60 and 80 Gb.

i have tried Environment Variables to increase imagemagick cache limits but, no results...

someone has some ideas about the white output?

Comment: How are you using `ImageMagick`? Command-line? PHP? Perl? Which version?  How do you integrate it with Vips DZSAVE? Do you get any error messages? What is your machine configuration?

Comment: Hi mark, i'm using dzsave inside a OS X app vips_dzsave(inputImage, target, "tile_size", [self.tile_size intValue], "overlap", [self.overlap intValue], NULL). VIPS version vips-7.40.6.  ImageMagick-6.8.9-7. No error. same problem on MacBook Pro retina 15" 8gb ram and macPro 32gbram

Answer (score 1):

I'm the vips maintainer. Try at the command-line, something like:

```
vips dzsave huge.psb output_name --tile-size 256 --overlap 0 --vips-progress --vips-leak
```

and see what happens. If you run "top" at the same time you can watch memory use.

vips uses libMagick to load the psb files and my guess would be that this is hitting a memory limit somewhere inside ImageMagick.

Do you have to use psb? If you can use a format that vips can process directly it should work much better. Big TIFF or Openslide (if these are slide images) are both good choices. I regularly process 200,000 x 200,000 images with dzsave on a very modest laptop.

Comment: hi, Thanks for your feedback... unfortunately i'm having this errorVipsForeignLoad: file "huge.psb" not found
memory: high-water mark 0 bytes

Comment: Hiya, that's the input file name. Swap it for the name of the .psb file you want to process. There's a blog post about how to use dzsave at the command-line here: http://libvips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/making-deepzoom-zoomify-and-google-maps.html

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding what I have to do... i have understood how to use dzsave, and with jpg is working, but with psb i'm ending in error even with other commands like shrink etc... how can i swap the file?

Comment: Is this with all .psb files, or just with huge ones? What is the error message? If it's all .psb files, you need to configure vips with ImageMagick load support, see http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=Build_on_OS_X. If it's only huge .psb files, then the problem is the .psb format itself and you need to pick a different file format.

Comment: stackoverflow isn't a great place to debug problems. Open an issue on the vips tracker and I'll try to help there https://github.com/jcupitt/libvips/issues